# Design an Access Form to Use Different Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I had an Access Form that works very well for my customer, however they want 3 identical forms, but with different underrunning queries for different types of searches. I could copy and paste the same form and attach the different queries, but this can become a huge maintenance and maintainability issue. Is it possible to use multiple queries on the same form, or change out the query before opening the form?

Comment: Is there any way you could just make them into one query with a parameter?

Comment: This database is used to manage projects. The query generates data for the same form, but the criteria or parameter varies for each query [Show forms by project ID in query 1, show forms by project name for query 2, show projects by project owner. The output data is the same, but the criteria needs to be different for each query.

Comment: But the output is different. One groups by project id, one groups by project name, one groups by owner. You might find that in future these forms diverge meaning that it would be a good idea to create three separate forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your different queries all return the same `SELECT` field expressions, but have different `WHERE` clauses.

If that is true, use a base query without a `WHERE` clause as the form's *Record Source*.  Then you can essentially add a `WHERE` clause "on the fly" by using the `DoCmd.OpenForm` method's *WhereCondition* option when you open the form.

```vb
Const cstrForm As String = "YourForm"
Dim strWhereCondition As String
```

Load *strWhereCondition* based on which dataset you want the form to display.  These 3 examples assume the form's *Record Source* includes fields named *proj id*, *proj name*, and *owner id* whose datatypes are numeric, text, and numeric respectively:

```vb
strWhereCondition = "[proj id]=" & SomeNumber
strWhereCondition = "[proj name]='" & SomeText & "'"
strWhereCondition = "[owner id]=" & SomeOtherNumber
```

Then open your form filtered by *strWhereCondition*:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=cstrForm, WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```

Comment: For the where condition, do I need to include parentheses if my original sql query has complex parentheses around my where condition?

Comment: The Access query designer tends to add way more parentheses than required, so I'll guess no.  But we would need to see an example to know for sure.

Comment: I am close to passing the whereCondition. I created whereConditions individiually and tested them to make sure their syntax would work. I then switched to making them dynamic strings. However  the macro is not recognizing the tempVar the string is placed in. I end up with a command like "OpenForm(Query, , [TempVars]![strWhereCondition], , Normal).Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Could you use a VBA procedure instead of a macro for this, and then show the VBA?

Comment: I'm avoiding VBA. The customer of this database is non-IT and they don't have long term IT support. If I can give them macros with prompts and summaries, that is a little more readable for them.. I'll see if I can include pictures.